# Django Model Field Inline

Tags: python, django

In Django, you can use inline to make new instances of models by just clicking the add instance button on the bottom of the admin site.
Is there a way to do this for a model field inside a model.
For example, if you were cataloging a book and you want to capture all the chapters in each books name. Every book has a different number of chapters so you could not just do

```
chapter1 = CharField(max_length = 200)
chapter2 = CharField(max_length = 200)
```

and so on. Like the picture below but not for model instances for model fields.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can model the `Book` and its chapters with:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then we can work with a [**`TabularInline`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline), and write this as:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ChapterInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Chapter

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ChapterInline,
    ]
```